# Does WP-WooC support filters at database?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database

Is it possible for WP-WooCommerce to add to a database some direct filters with restriction conditions for example like: if (table_users.user_role<1) then (post_content="register to see")? Does WP-WooC each request to DB have a user ID and full string? or it cashing some db data? or not all requests contain a user_ID? Clarify, please!

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: As I say, I just want to hide for unregistered users some information from DB for all possible places of site (WooC Product Attributes Values). So if make it at WP-WooC level it must be also made for all plugins etc, many code, some hooks priorities conflicts, etc. But directly at DB maybe it can be made as just one simple global filter?